# Floating Point Arithmetic, C output

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

for which value of f, the output will be "world"?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  float f= ... ;
  if(f==f)
     printf("hello\n");
  else
     printf("world\n");
 return 0;
}
```

what will be replaced with three dots (...)

Comment: don't use any function or any trick ... please suggest me some arithmetic value which is float.

Comment: @Rahul: You already have like 5 below.  :)

Comment: @Listing No, infinities are equalt to themselves, you need a NaN.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the find, I expected it to evaluate to NaN as the program can't know for sure if 0.0f is "positive or negative".

Comment: @Listing If the IEEE specs are followed, `x/0.0f` is positive infinity if `x > 0`, negative if `x < 0` and NaN if `x == 0`; note that `-0.0f == 0.0f`. Signs are reversed if dividing by `-0.0f`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
  float f = nanf("0.0");
  printf("%f\n", f);

  if(f==f)
     printf("hello\n");
  else
     printf("world\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is probably what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

```
float f = (puts("world"), exit(0), 0.0f);
```

**Edit:** Yes, I know you're looking for a different answer.  But I'm going to be cute instead because this looks like a problem from a homework assignment or take-home quiz that hasn't even been broken down into its parts.

Comment: only some arithmetic value... can u suggest one?

Comment: aah! @Dietrich Epp. U beat me to it by 2 seconds! :-)

Answer (score 2):

IEEE 754 floating point numbers can represent positive or negative `infinity` and `NaN` (not a number). These 3 values arise from calculations whose result is undefined or cannot be represented accurately. `NaN` will **always** propagate through expressions. i.e. any expression containing `NaN` **will** evaluate `NaN`.

You can also deliberately set a floating-point variable to `NaN`. For example, the following perfectly valid floating-point expression will do the trick :

```
 sqrtf(-1.0f) // NaN
```

More info on [**infinity** and **NaN** in floating point numbers](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html).

---

PS: I was tempted to ignore this as it looks like a straightforward homework Q. But what with the homework tag being deprecated and all...

Comment: To be fair, it could be an interview question as well.  :)

Comment: :) :) @cHao I hope he gets the job ;-) ;-)

Comment: Infinity compared to itself would yield true, just like any plain number. The only value that doesn't do this is NaN. Also, your statement about infinity is not really true, as there are cases where an input with infinity would yield a NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NAN` macro from `math.h`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float f = NAN;
  if (f == f)
     printf("hello\n");
  else
     printf("world\n");
}
```

Note that this macro has been introduced in C99 and is not present if the implementation does not support quiet NaNs for the `float` type.